# How to convert raw HTML dynamically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

**I want to show this table on the frontend Product View page**

**How to replace `{{custom_product_attribute_1}}` with actual product attribute value. and these attributes can be dynamic.**

**Custom RAW HTML Template -**

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 16.6667%;">{{custom_product_attribute_1}}</td>
            <td style="width: 16.6667%;">{{custom_product_attribute_2}}</td>
            <td style="width: 16.6667%;">{{custom_product_attribute_3}}</td>
            ........
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Expected Result:-**

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 16.6667%;">10</td>
            <td style="width: 16.6667%;">15</td>
            <td style="width: 16.6667%;">30</td>
            ........
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**I am using Admin to create HTML templates.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you need to use a HTML template?

Typically (unless creating a UI component with Knockout JS), you would use a PHTML template for that sort of thing.

`template-name.phtml` (example, although there are other ways to achieve the same thing)

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$attributeOne = $product->getData('custom_product_attribute') ?> 
?>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 16.6667%;"><?= $attributeOne ?></td>
            ........
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In your XML, set the class as `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description` which will give you access to the `getProduct` method. e.g.

```
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="custom.template" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/template-name.phtml" />
```

Comment: actually, I am using admin to create HTML Templates. one template can be associated with many products.... see the attached image in the above question.

Comment: That will not work...as I don't know what attribute is used in the template...so can't use this code --> $attributeOne = $product->getData('custom_product_attribute') ?>

Comment: Ah for use in admin; In that case you won't be able to use the PHP code above. But also in this case, if you wanted these attributes to be dynamic, you wouldn't be able to apply your logic directly in the HTML. Is there any reason why it needs to be editable in the HTML admin template? If these are dynamic attributes then surely would be easier to loop through an attribute set and render the values if present inside a PHTML file?